# exiting infinite wait of one thread with input from another in java

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop, hotkeys

I am making a Java app which does something on a HotKey combination. I have an infinite while loop to wait for HotKey input to close, but it makes the app very CPU time costing.

Following is how my code looks in the simplest way:

```
static boolean isOpen = true;
void main()
{
    ....
    add SomeHotKeyListener();
    ....
    while(isOpen)
    {  }
    releaseResources();
}

void onHotKey(int hotKeyIdentifier)
{
    if(hotKeyIdentifier == something)
      do something;
    if(hotKeyIdentifier == something)
      isOpen = false;
}
```

I need a multi-threading approach to achieve this, or if someone has something better to fit in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read about the `synchronized` keyword in Java. Just [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+synchronized), and you should find a ton of examples and [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm).

This should solve your case:

```
static boolean isOpen = true;
static Object lock = new Object();
void main()
{
    ....
    add SomeHotKeyListener();
    ....
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        while(isOpen)
        {
            try {
                lock.wait()
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    releaseResources();
}

void onHotKey(int hotKeyIdentifier)
{
    if(hotKeyIdentifier == something)
        do something;
    if(hotKeyIdentifier == something)
    {
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            isOpen = false;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. One thing I forgot though (and zencv mentioned in his/her reply) is to make `isOpen` volatile, which is very important to make sure that both threads are accessing the same memory when referring to that variable, as explained [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).

Comment: what is the need of using a volatile variable in this case, as your earlier solution of wait and notify in a synchronized block suffice the need?

Comment: I rescind my previous comment. You are correct, as using the synchronized block establishes a [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) relationship with any other synchronized block on the same object, thus making all changes within the synchronized block accessible from any other synchronized block on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite while loop can consume quite a lot of system resource. Using wait and notify is recommended. Also you have to declare your boolean `volatile` as otherwise there is no guarantee that the changes made by one thread is picked up by the other. Below is an example which does something in a separate thread and until interrupted by the calling thread based on a user input (an enter in this case). See also the example from Oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WaitTest implements Runnable {

private volatile boolean shutdown = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WaitTest w = new WaitTest();

    new Thread(w).start();

    System.out.println("Press any key to interrupt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.nextLine();

    w.triggerShutDown();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                System.out.println("doing some silly things");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Server shutdown successfully");
}

public synchronized void triggerShutDown() {
    this.shutdown = true;
    notify();
}
}
```

Comment: i read the following line in Oracle docs : "when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. **This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads**". Find the source [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).
Is it necessary to use a volatile variable for same thread usage and not for others?

Comment: In this case the `volatile` keyword is actually needed. Reason is there is a case where `shutdown` can be accessed concurrently from two threads, where there's no other defense mechanism. This happens on the first line in the `run()` function. If all accesses to `shutdown` were within synchronized code, this wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: Note that in my answer I solved this by putting the `while (!shutdown)` within the synchronized block. My solution is better when I expect the encapsulating function `main()` to be called only once. zencv's solution is better when you expect the encapsulating function `run()` to be called more than once (because in subsequent calls, it will immediately identify `shutdown` as `true`, and will not need to enter the synchronized code at all. Remember that entering synchronized code bears a cost).